# Basic Single Line Function

Tags: c

I am trying to create a simple(supposedly) single line function named `f2` that takes one int argument named `x`, and returns a double value equal to `1.0/x` but doesn't print anything. I am getting error after error, and I am not sure what the protocols are for creating and separating different parts of a function on one line or if I can even do this. Here is what I have:

```
f2(int x) { scanf("%i", &x); int c = (1.0/x) return x}
```

I am trying to use ch to see if it runs and I am not sure if that could, possibly, also be the problem.

Comment: You need a `;`before your return statement, or is this a typo?

Comment: Dont put comments in edits. make changes and leave a comment as a comment. Don't go changing their code either. If you're not 10000% sure that it was a typo then it could have been the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't do any part of what you specify...

There is no reason to use scanf. You also use an int to store a floating point value. You also don't return the calculated value.

Here is your function, expanded for clarity:

```
double f2(int x){
    double val = 1.0 / x;
    return val;
}
```

One line:

```
double f2(int x){ return 1.0 / x; }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
double f2(int x){ return 1.0/x; }
```